# Lossless Compression Books

Tags: reference-request, ds.data-structures, books

I am intrigued by compression techniques and I'd like some recommendations about books to study, specifically, on **lossless** compression algorithms and data structures.

I don't know if there is a comprehensive book (or books) that deals with both compression of general sources (stream of bytes), and known inputs (e.g., integers, strings).

Thanks for your references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following books:

- Khalid Sayood "Introduction to DATA COMPRESSION"
- Khalid Sayood "Lossless Compression Handbook"
- David Salomon "Handbook of Data compression"

And a little more specific, but also good books in this field:

- Timothy Bell "Text compression"
- Donald Adjeroh, Timothy Bell, Amar Mukherjee "The Burrows-Wheeler Transform: Data Compression, Suffix Arrays, and Pattern
  Matching"